# How do I "post mortem" a "Caught Exception" in Python in VS.Code?

Tags: python, vscode-python

In VS.Code with the Python extension, I can break on "Uncaught Exceptions" and "Raised Exceptions".

But what if I don't want to break on all exceptions, only those that are uncaught in a certain function? (but which are caught, say by a framework like FastAPI, in a shallower frame?)

If debugging on the console, when I know there is a function that has a line causing an exception, I can change it from something like this:

```py
def some_function():
    line_causing_some_exception()
```

To this:

```py
def some_function():
    try:
        line_causing_some_exception()
    except:
        import pdb
        pdb.post_mortem()
        # Let the framework handle the exception as usual:
        raise
```

I can even debug graphically, instead of depending on the console, by using the excellent [wdb](https://github.com/Kozea/wdb), which is very handy for server apps, or for when I'm not launching the python code directly and have no access to its console:

```py
def some_function():
    try:
        line_causing_some_exception()
    except:
        import wdb
        wdb.post_mortem()
        # Let the framework handle the exception as usual:
        raise
```

In VS.Code, if I add a breakpoint after catching the exception, I don't have the "post mortem" traceback, only the current frame:

```py
def some_function():
    try:
        line_causing_some_exception()
    except:
        import debugpy
        debugpy.breakpoint()
        # Let the framework handle the exception as usual:
        raise
```

I couldn't find an equivalent `debugpy.post_mortem()` as there is for `pdb` and `wdb`.

How can I trigger a post-mortem debugging explicitly, similar to the "Uncaught Exceptions" checkbox, but for exceptions that are going to be caught on earlier frames?

Comment: exceptionBreakpointFilters / setExceptionBreakpoints is VS Code may do what you want, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/275)